# Why does PowerShell not work if I use WinRS?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, invoke-command, remote-execution, winrs

I have a file "test.ps1" and its content is as below:

```
$getRSDBName =
{
    Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $rsdb = Get-SPRSDatabase

    return $rsdb
}


$rsdb = invoke-command  -scriptblock $getRSDBName 

$rsdb
```

It work if I call it as:

```
powershell -f c:\test.ps1
```

I get an error if I use WinRS:

```
winrs -r:xxxxx -u:xxxxxx -p:xxxxx powershell -f c:\test.ps1
```

I also tried it by inputting `-Authentication CredSSP -Credential $creds` as parameters of `Invoke-Command`, but I got the same result as before.  In both instances, the error is:

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
>   not registered. Get-SPRSDatabase : Cannot access the local farm.
>   Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently
>   available, and that you have the appropriate per missions to access
>   the database before trying again.
>       At C:\clean.ps1:181 char:29
>       +     $rsdb = Get-SPRSDatabase <<<<
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Repor...ServiceDatabase:
>          GetReportingServiceDatabase) [Get-SPRSDatabase], SPCmdletException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.PowerShell.GetReportingServiceDatabase

Could someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Is PowerShell Remoting [enabled](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx) on the remote host? Does the execution policy on all hosts allow execution of PowerShell scripts?

Answer (score 1):

that's caused by the "second hop" issue described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj853299.aspx) when the commandlet on the remote server tries in turn to reach the sql database (it has to pass credential to it, but they cannot be delegated a second time)

to solve it run the following on the server

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role server
```

and this on the client (requires elevated privileges)

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP –Role client –DelegateComputer *
```

then remember to use

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Credential $credential -Authentication CredSSP
```

when you open the remote session, and pass $session to invoke-command

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $doSomething -Session $session
```

this solved for me :) in general i've found that any strange issue i find when using invoke-command is somehow related to the second hop problem. That actually is a security feature, therefore it is here for help us even if it is a little boring, but is not that hard to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create a PS-Session and then run the script within that remote shell? If so, why not add a create/destroy session to your current script?

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "computerNameHere"
Import-PSSession -Session $Session

$getRSDBName = {
    Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $rsdb = Get-SPRSDatabase

    return $rsdb
}
$rsdb = invoke-command  -scriptblock $getRSDBName 
$rsdb

Remove-PSSession -ComputerName "computerNameHere"
```